# I want to make a new grid same to another one

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I made a grid  in Microsoft expression blend 4 this grid has buttons and I want to make a new grid same to this grid but using c# and add it to new tab control how ?

Comment: do you mean a Grid or a DataGrid? does a style or controltemplate will help you?

Comment: I mean Grid i want it the same to original one in color and texts and every thing like i make a copy of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either implement a DataTemplate to draw your grid, or convert it into a UserControl.

Either way, after you perform this, you may create a TabControl and add Templated data to its DataContext or a User Control to each Tab.

---

**To create a UserControl:**
If you are using Blend just right click the Grid object you want to copy and select "Make into UserControl..."
Then you may add the created UserControl to any place in your project, just like using a common toolbox item.

**To create a Template** I suggest you read [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Templates.html), as you need not only to know how to create one, but also the concept of using templates, witch I truly recommend for your situation.

Regards

Comment: if you can give me an example for the 2 solutions please i will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

You could put the collection that both grids are going to bind to on the main ViewModel.  Then, the grid on each tab could be different, but looking at the same data.  An example of two grids binding to the same collection can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264978/interactive-wpf-relational-datagrid-system-samples/5265771#5265771).

If you want both grids to be the same, then I'd agree with @gjsduarte and create a UserControl that you place on both tabs.

Note:  The link that I shared is for Silverlight, but the concept is the same.